# send friend request to user using xmpp and openfire

Tags: ios, iphone, xmpp, openfire, xmppframework

hello i have used openfire as a server and want to send friend request for that i am using following code

```
- (XMPPRoster *)xmppRoster {
    return [[self appDelegate] xmppRoster];
}

-(IBAction)SendFriendRequest:(id)sender
{
    XMPPJID *newBuddy = [XMPPJID jidWithString:@"test1@192.168.4.21"];

    [[[self appDelegate]xmppRoster]addUser:newBuddy withNickname:@"test user 1"];
}
```

i am getting this type of log

```
<iq xmlns="jabber:client" type="error" to="192.168.4.21/de4fd927"><query xmlns="jabber:iq:roster"><item jid="test1@192.168.4.21" name="test user 3"></item></query><error code="401" type="auth"><not-authorized xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas"></not-authorized></error></iq>
```

i am unable to send request to "test1" has been logged in spark.

Any help would be appreciable!

Answer (score 1):

1. Every XMPP entity, which can exchange XMPP packets with other entity, should have JID in username@domain.tld form, you are trying to use IP address instead of domain name, which is possible, but potentially can give unexpectable errors.
2. You should be authenticated at server before you able to exchange packets with others.

Answer (score 1):

It seem you have not initialised xmppRoster in setupStream method:

Please try to write the following code in setup stream:

```
xmppRosterStorage = [[XMPPRosterCoreDataStorage alloc] initWithInMemoryStore];

xmppRoster = [[XMPPRoster alloc] initWithRosterStorage:xmppRosterStorage];

xmppRoster.autoFetchRoster = YES;
xmppRoster.autoAcceptKnownPresenceSubscriptionRequests = YES;

[xmppRoster addDelegate:self delegateQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];

[xmppRoster activate:xmppStream];
```

Hope it will give some help

Comment: Is there any way to send the friend request to offline user?

Comment: Yes, You can send friend request to offline user and on other side, whenever requested user will be online will get the request. 

Here is the code :

XMPPJID *newBuddy = [XMPPJID jidWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Friendname@YourServer.com"]];       
            
[[self xmppRoster] addUser:newBuddy withNickname:Nil];